# Matching color of "icon-home" in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, colors, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to match the color of the home icon using twitter bootstrap to the color of the inactive text like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav_item"><a href="indexdefaults.html"><i class="icon-home icon-gray"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the "icon-gray" class is much darker than the text in the "nav_item" class.  What is the appropriate class icon-foobar that matches the color of the nav_item text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two variations to the icons, white and dark, if you want to get a different colored set of icons you have to modify the original icons in photoshop or pay for the full icon set and modify the source files. There is no `.icon-gray`.

Answer (score 10):

You can get the gray color by using a custom style:

```
.icon-gray {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

You might have to change the opacity lower or higher as per the weight of black.

Comment: This works perfectly. For a discreet grey I would suggest to tone the opacity down to 0.3

Comment: Good call on 'opacity: 0.3'.  Looks great.

Comment: vincentjacquel and @PeterBloom: edited the answer according to your comments. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just integrate: Font Awesome which is working fine with Bootstrap without editing image and you can change the color of the icon just like you do for text:

```
.icon-gray {color:#696969;}
```

Font Awesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Find CSS Match color: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp